# Primefaces Dialog Update after it is open

Tags: ajax, primefaces, dialog

I want to update content primafaces dialog after it is opened.   Is it possible? My example code is below.

```
 <p:dialog widgetVar="pictureSaveDialog" id="pictureDialog" closable="false" >
   <p:outputPanel id="saveDialogPanel">

   <p:selectOneRadio id="options" value="#{pictureDefinitionsView.radioValue}"  >  
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="FILE" itemValue="FILE" />  
                <f:selectItem itemLabel=""  itemValue="URL" />  
         <p:ajax update="fileUpload1 fileUpload2" event="click" process="options"  />
   </p:selectOneRadio>

   <p:outputPanel id="fileUpload1" rendered="#{pictureDefinitionsView.selectedFileUpload}">   File </p:outputPanel>

 <p:outputPanel id="fileUpload2" rendered="#{pictureDefinitionsView.selectedUrlUpload}">   URL </p:outputPanel>
</p:outputPanel id="saveDialogPanel">
```

Bean Methods.

```
    public boolean isSelectedFileUpload(){
    return radioValue.equals("FILE");
    } 
public boolean isSelectedUrlUpload(){
    return !isSelectedFileUpload();
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

You can define `p:remoteCommand` which just update dialog, and call that command in `onShow` attribute:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="updateDialog" update="saveDialogPanel"/>

<p:dialog widgetVar="pictureSaveDialog" id="pictureDialog" closable="false" onShow="updateDialog()">
```

If your `saveDialogPanel` is in some naming container be shore to add appropriate prefix to match id of component.

Comment: Please provide some more explanation like programmer, not like user. What does it mean didn't work. See JavaScript console, see Java console, see generated HTML.

Comment: sorry. I want that after dialog is open, I select other radio option after  the outputpanel which has id fileUpload1  will hide and other outputpanel will show. when i select other radio option , the outputpanel which has id fileUpload2 will show and fileUpload1 will close. I hope , you will understand despite my english.

Comment: This is easiest way to let popup update it's self on show.

Answer (score 3):

You better refresh the dialog content before its being open

Your p:commandButton/p:ajax should have the following:

```
update="pictureDialog" onsuccess="pictureSaveDialog.show()"
```

Comment: i want to refresh after the dialog is open.

Comment: its the same thing , in both cases you will show the dialog with updated values...

Comment: I couldn't tell explain my question. I explained with detail under partlov's answer. I chance options radiobuttons on the dialog and i want to chance dialog content without closing it.

Comment: so `update="pictureDialog"` is all you need to add in your `p:ajax`