# How to recreate dialog in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

I have a dialog which would like to be recreated rather than re-displayed with the current content. I use:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dialogId').show()");
```

to show dialog and

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dialogId').hide()");
```

to hide dialog from the backing bean.

If I use

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dialogId').content.empty()");
```

before show() then dialog is empty.

I have also tried

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dialogId').remove()");
```

before show() but dialog is not shown at all.

The reason I want to recreate rather then re-display is because I create TreeNodes in the dialog bean init function. The Treenodes data has to be obtained from database before dialog is displayed.

I just want dialog bean's init function to be called every time dialog is displayed rather the just the first time.

My init function:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root Node", null);
    // code for creating other TreeNodes
}
```

Comment: please reformatte your question it's hard to read it [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Primefaces Dialog Update after it is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244932/primefaces-dialog-update-after-it-is-open)

Comment: I have reformatted question.

I have tried both solutions but dialog's init function is still not called when dialog is redisplayed.

Comment: How do you call the init function? Post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have added init function to my question above.. I have also tried replacing init function by default constructor but it is also only called when dialog is displayed first time.

Comment: You know that @PostConstruct is always only called once on bean creation time? So either you need a bean scope which fits your needs, or you need to create your nodes in an extra method which is called via remoteCommand every time the dialog is shown and then updates your dialog. (like the answer in my duplicate link)

Comment: I know @PostConstruct is always only called once on bean creation time and for that reason I wanted to destroy and then recreate dialog.